# Flip animation in canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

How to make flip a bitmap in android canvas.?

I can flip the views using animation class but how to flip the  bitmap in canvas.?

by using `canvas.rotate(x)`; I can rotate the canvas selected path but my requirement is to flip.. 
can some one help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Matrix` for that:

```
final Matrix matrix = new Matrix();  

matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
matrix.postTranslate(positionX, positionY);                     

canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint);
```